# DIfference between signed and unsigned practically

Tags: java, unsigned-integer

I've searched and read many previous answers concerning this difference but I still don't get somethings, for example with this line of code :

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2));
```

I read that Unsigned can hold a larger positive value, and no negative value. Unsigned uses the leading bit as a part of the value, while the signed version uses the left-most-bit to identify if the number is positive or negative. signed integers can hold both positive and negative numbers. A Unisgned can go larger than MAX_VALUE, so why is that sysout gives -1 which is negative. And for this line code :

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2));
```

Why does this line gives an error(32 times 1) ? Isn't a signed int suppose to treat the first 1 as a minus, and the other 31 1's as the positive value ? (so it should give - MAX_VALUE)

Comment: @markspace The second parameter specifies the radix (in this case 2, so it does process binary).

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Didn't scroll all the way to the right so didn't see the second parameter.  Maybe the OP should break up those long lines?  But anyway the second version still doesn't use bits, it'll use a minus sign just like the decimal version.

Comment: It's not correct that the signed integer representation uses the leading bit as a minus.  It's part of the value in both signed and unsigned cases.  In an unsigned integer, the leading bit is worth 2^31.  In a signed integer it's worth -2^31.  That is the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

Java *does not have* unsigned integer types.  When you call `parseUnsignedInt`, it does *not* return an unsigned integer, because there is no such thing in java.

Instead, `parseUnsignedInt` parses the input as an unsigned 32-bit value, and then returns the *signed* 32-bit value with the *same bits*.

If you provide it with a number that has the leading bit set in its unsigned representation, it will therefore return a negative number, because all the *signed* numbers with that bit set are negative.

Comment: Upvoted as saying more succinctly what I attempted to express.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this line gives an error(32 times 1) ? Isn't a signed int
>   suppose to treat the first 1 as a minus, and the other 31 1's as the
>   positive value ? (so it should give - MAX_VALUE)

It throws a `NumberFormatException` for exactly the same reason that

```
Integer.parseInt("2147483648", 10)
```

does.  The string does not represent a number that can be represented as an `int` when interpreted according to the specified radix.  That `int` uses 32 bits to represent values is only peripherally related.  If you want to parse a negative value with `Integer.parseInt()` then the string should contain a leading minus sign:

```
Integer.parseInt("-1111111111111111111111111111111", 2)
```

or even

```
Integer.parseInt("-10000000000000000000000000000000", 2)  // note: 32 digits
```

The method is not mapping bits directly to an `int` representation.  It is interpreting the string as a textual representation of a number.

Comment: But I still don't understand that if unsigned int contains only positive integers, how could it give  a negative one, in other words, why in the case of 32 digits does parseUnsignedInt interpret the string as a two's complement ? Normally it's the signed integer that should be interpreted like a two's complement.

Comment: There is nothing in an ```Integer``` to say how the bits got there - from a function that regarded them as unsigned bits or from a function that regarded them as signed bits.  So the formatting code treats them in the conventional Java way, as a signed value.

Comment: @Ino, because `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` parses the value as an unigned integer with 32 bits, and then ***maps*** the result to an `int`, using a mapping that represents positive values between (the arithmetic values of) `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 1` as negative numbers.  This is described in its docs, but in fact, it *is* a little strange, which may be why the method didn't exist before Java 8.  Nevertheless, there wouldn't be any point to the method if it didn't do something like that, because there is no `int` representation of numbers above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

> A Unsigned can go larger than MAX_VALUE, so why is that sysout gives
>   -1 which is negative.

`Integer` holds a 32-bit value.  The result of parseUnsignedInt(32 one-bits, 2) is a value with all bits set.  What that "means" is in the eye of the beholder.  Most of Java considers integer values to be signed. The formatter used by `println`, for example, regards the value as signed, and the result is `-1`.

All you really have 'inside' the Integer is a 32-bit value. parseUnsignedInt() handles its input argument specially, but then it has to store the result in a standard Integer.  There is nothing to say that the bits are supposed to be 'unsigned'. If you want to treat the value as unsigned, you can't use anything that treats it as signed, since Java really does not have an unsigned-integer type.

> Isn't a signed int suppose to treat the first 1 as a minus, and the
>   other 31 1's as the positive value ? (so it should give - MAX_VALUE)

See other answer for this part.

The representation I think you were expecting, where the high bit indicates the sign and the rest of the bits indicates the (positive) value, is called "sign and magnitude" representation. I am unaware of any current computer that uses sign-and-magnitude for its integers (may have happened in the very early days, 1950s or so, when people were getting to grips with this stuff).

Comment: I know that java interprets integers as signed, that's why I didn't understand. I used parseUnsignedInt so that I could have an unsigned interpretation but in the case of 32 bits it still gave me a two's complement which is equivalent to signed, so that method makes no sense if it doesn't give me unsigned interpretation in all cases.

Comment: Updated my answer in the hope of explaining it further.